# WebFlow design and Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

our design team is using WebFlow to design our new web application, however our development team is using Polymer 2.0 (started the app with the blank application template in Polymer CLI).  When the design team exports their design from the WebFlow editor it outputs 3 css files (site.webflow.css, normalize.css, webflow.css), the html files and 2 js files (modernize.js, webflow.js).  We can figure out how to get the css files incorporated into the Polymer 2.0 app, but we are stuck trying to understand how to import the js files.  The webflow.js file includes all the interactions etc.  I can send the WebFlow design output to anyone if that would help.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can easily add `script` tag outside of Polymer element and then use some code from your js files. Show more examples please